# snprintf vs. strcpy (etc.) in C

Tags: c, string, printf

For doing string concatenation, I've been doing basic `strcpy`, `strncpy` of char* buffers. Then I learned about the `snprintf` and friends.

Should I stick with my `strcpy`, `strcpy` + `\0` termination? Or should I just use `snprintf` in the future?

Comment: `strncpy` is completely out of place here. `strncpy` should not be used for limited-length string copying. This is not what that function does and this is not what it was developed for. The appropriate counterpart for `snprintf` in this context would be `strlcpy` (albeit it is not standard).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For most purposes I doubt the difference between using [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) and [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) is measurable.

If there's any formatting involved I tend to stick to only [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) rather than mixing in [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) as well.

I find this helps code clarity, and means you can use the following idiom to keep track of where you are in the buffer (thus avoiding creating a [Shlemiel the Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) algorithm):

```
char sBuffer[iBufferSize];
char* pCursor = sBuffer;

pCursor += snprintf(pCursor, sizeof(sBuffer) - (pCursor - sBuffer),  "some stuff\n");

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   pCursor += snprintf(pCursor, sizeof(sBuffer) - (pCursor - sBuffer),  " iter %d\n", i);
}

pCursor += snprintf(pCursor, sizeof(sBuffer) - (pCursor - sBuffer),  "into a string\n");
```

Comment: It'd be even clearer if you used a single call to `snprintf`.  And be aware that if the buffer isn't large enough, `snprintf` will return the necessary buffer size (or a negative number on failure), so incrementing `pCursor` like that can be dangerous.

Comment: Do a s/snprint/snprintf/ in your code. Also, your example doesn't make sense. I'd stick to formatters.

Comment: @jweyrich - whoops, thanks fixed function name.  Yeah, it's a dumb example, made it a bit more useful.

Comment: @jamesdlin - yeah, I know, either needs to have known bounds on the string size or some error checking.

Comment: man snprintf "If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned."

Answer (score 10):

As others did point out already: Do not use strncpy.

- strncpy will not zero terminate in case of truncation.
- strncpy will zero-pad the whole buffer if string is shorter than buffer. If buffer is large, this may be a performance drain.

snprintf will (on POSIX platforms) zero-terminate. On Windows, there is only _snprintf, which will not zero-terminate, so take that into account.

Note: when using snprintf, use this form:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s", string);
```

instead of

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), string);
```

The latter is insecure and - if string depends on user input - can lead to stack smashes, etc.

Comment: This inconsistency is a very confusing part for libc.

Answer (score 5):

snprintf is more robust if you want to format your string. If you only want to concatenate, use strncpy (don't use strcpy) since it's more efficient.

Comment: Quote from Linux man on strncpy: "Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated." So it's not only about efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is another difference between strncpy and snprintf.

Think about this:

```
const int N=1000000;
char arr[N];
strncpy(arr, "abce", N);
```

Usually, strncpy will set the rest of the destination buffer to '\0'. This will cost lots of CPU time. While when you call snprintf,

```
snprintf(a, N, "%s", "abce");
```

it will leave the buffer unchanged.

I don't know why strncpy will do that, but in this case, I will choose snprintf instead of strncpy.

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf` has an extremely useful return value that allows for efficient appending.

Here's the idiom:

```
char buffer[HUGE] = {0}; 
char *end_of_string = &buffer[0];
end_of_string += sprintf( /* whatever */ );
end_of_string += sprintf( /* whatever */ );
end_of_string += sprintf( /* whatever */ );
```

You get the idea.  This works because `sprintf` returns the number of characters it wrote to the buffer, so advancing your buffer by that many positions will leave you pointing to the `'\0'` at the end of what's been written so far.  So when you hand the updated position to the next `sprintf`, it can start writing new characters right there.

Constrast with `strcpy`, whose return value is required to be useless.  It hands you back the same argument you passed it.  So appending with `strcpy` implies traversing the entire first string looking for the end of it.  And then appending again with another strcpy call implies traversing the entire first string, followed by the 2nd string that now lives after it, looking for the `'\0'`.  A third `strcpy` will re-traverse the strings that have already been written yet again.  And so forth.

So for many small appends to a very large buffer, `strcpy` approches (O^n) where n is the number of appends.  Which is terrible.

Plus, as others mentioned, they do different things.  `sprintf` can be used to format numbers, pointer values, etc, into your buffer.

Comment: Woops, I just noticed you asked specifically about snprintf.  The idiom can still work, but you need to also keep a running count of how few characters remain in the buffer.  It then becomes `written = snprintf(buf, remanining, ...);  buf += written;  remaining -= written; `

Comment: Extra care is needed with `snprintf`.  See my comment to therefromhere's answer.

Comment: As you noticed, the question is about `snprintf()` not `sprintf()`. Watch out for errors in the return value from `snprintf()` though! It could be negative! See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/.

Answer (score 2):

All *printf functions check formatting and expand its corresponding argument, thus it is slower than a simple strcpy/strncpy, which only copy a given number of bytes from linear memory.

My rule of thumb is:

- Use snprintf whenever formatting is needed.
- Stick to strncpy/memcpy when only need to copy a block of linear memory.
- You can use strcpy whenever you know exatcly the size of buffers you're copying. Don't use that if you don't have full control over the buffers size.

Answer (score 1):

strcpy, strncpy, etc. only copies strings from one memory location to another. But, with snprint, you can do more stuff like formatting the string. Copying integers into buffer, etc.

It purely depends on your requirement which one to use. If as per your logic, strcpy & strncpy is already working for you, there is no need to jump to snprintf.

Also, remember to use strncpy for better safety as suggested by others.

Comment: I know what you mean, but `strncpy` isn't restricted to reading (or even writing) NUL-terminated strings.

Comment: Yes, I know. Probably, I didn't phrase my answer correctly. I have edited it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between strncpy and snprintf is that strncpy basically lays  on you responsibility of terminating string with '\0'. It may terminate dst with '\0' but only if src is short enough.

Typical examples are:

```
strncpy(dst, src, n);
// if src is longer than n dst will not contain null
// terminated string at this point
dst[n - 1] = '\0';
```

```
snprintf(dst, n, "%s", src); // dst will 100% contain null terminated string
```