# Difference between strncpy and snprintf?

Tags: c

What is the difference between

```
strncpy(dst, src, n)
```

and

```
snprintf(dst, n, "%s", src)
```

Should I prefer one or the other when trying to do a bounded string copy? And if so, why?

Comment: One difference is that `snprintf` always NUL-terminates the string, but `strncpy` does not always do that. Is this previous question [snprintf vs. strcpy (etc.) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606539/snprintf-vs-strcpy-etc-in-c) relevant?

Comment: You should use *neither*. Not, unless you are forced to. There are better (= safer) functions to use: `strdup()`, `asprintf()`, `open_memstream()`, etc. Whenever you are writing something into a preallocated buffer, you are at the very least requiring yourself to be extremely cautious with error handling (*all* instances of insufficient space must be checked for and handled correctly). By using the functions I listed, you can just forget about that, because those functions allocate *sufficient* space themselves.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`strncpy` **is not a bounded `strcpy`**. It's a fixed-length (not bounded, fixed-length) operation targeting a destination that's not a C string (null-terminated) but a *null-padded* field, like what was used in certain kinds of data record tables in the 70s and early 80s. It has basically **no modern purpose** and should not be used unless you really want this behavior.

`snprintf` is the canonical C function for "bounded `strcpy`". On POSIX systems, `strnlen`+`memcpy` would be another good alternative, and necessary if you need to support strings longer than `INT_MAX`. If you don't have `strnlen`, you can easily make it with `memchr` and do the same.

Note that the simple use of `snprintf` is not "bounded" in the sense of having a bound on how much it reads from the source; it necessarily reads the whole source string to determine the return value, which both can incur a time cost and depends on the source being a valid (terminated) string. If you want it bounded in the sense of both source and destination, you can do something like:

```
snprintf(dest, n, "%.*s", (int)n-1, src);
```

However, that's sufficiently non-idiomatic and error-prone that I would just use `strnlen` and `memcpy` instead.

Comment: Interesting aspect about bounding the amount read from `src`.  Hmmmm.

Comment: @M.M: Is there a part of the answer you're disagreeing with based on that?

Comment: Never mind, I see now that by "simple use of snprintf" you mean the use of `%s` specifically (without precision)

Answer (score 6):

Use `snprintf(dst, n, "%s", src)`.

`snprintf(dst, n, "%s", src)` makes certain that `dst` is *null character* terminated.  `strncpy(dst, src, n)` does not do that.

`strncpy(dst, src, n)` always does `n` copies whereas `snprintf(dst, n "%s", src)` does `min(strlen(src),n)` copies