# Access array elements in a dynamic array of structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, realloc, memcpy

I am attempting to create a dynamic array of structs in C, I have tried to write the following code, an updated version of the original post after recommendations.

The structs I am trying to add to my array are located in a text_interface.h file as follows;

```
struct string 
{
    int type;
    int length;
    char *data;
};
```

Which is created with the following code snippet located in a text_interface.c file;

```
struct string * makeString(const char *s)
{
    struct string *s2;

    s2 = malloc(sizeof(struct string));
    if(s2 == 0) return 0;

    s2->length = strlen(s);

    s2->data = malloc(s2->length);
    if(s2->data == 0) 
    {
        free(s2);
        return 0;
    }

    snprintf ( s2->data, s2->length, "%s", s );

    return s2;
}
```

my Array struct looks like this, located in my array.h file;

```
typedef struct 
{
    int type;
    size_t size;
    void *array;
} Array;
```

I declare my Console_Array as a global variable in a common.h and common.c file as follows;

```
extern Array Console_Array; // In common.h

Array Console_Array;// In common.c
```

I then initialize the array using this function, located in my array.c file;

```
// Initialize an empty array
void Array_Init(Array *array, int type) 
{

    if(type == STRING_ARRAY)
    {
        struct string *sstr_pointer;
        sstr_pointer = makeString("NULL");
        if(sstr_pointer == NULL)
        {       
            printf("Struct String Array Error - Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
            free(sstr_pointer);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            array->type = type;
            array->array = sstr_pointer; 
            array->size = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

I have defined constants located in my array.h file;

```
#define INT_ARRAY    1
#define CHAR_ARRAY   2
#define STRING_ARRAY 3
#define VOID_ARRAY   4
```

My add to array function looks similar to this, located in my array.h file;

```
// Dynamically add to end of an array
void Array_Add(Array *array, void *item) 
{

    //----------------------
    // STRING ARRAY
    if(array->type == STRING_ARRAY)
    {
        printf("@:- String Array Type Detected - Copying Item %d To String Array\n", array->size+1);
    
        void *array_pointer; 
        int num_bytes;

        if(array->size >= 1)
        {
            num_bytes = (array->size+1)*(sizeof(struct string));
            printf("+ Number of bytes to reallocate (%d)\n", num_bytes);
        
            array_pointer = realloc(array->array, num_bytes);
        
            if(array_pointer == NULL)
            {       
                printf("Unable to reallocate memory, exiting.\n\n");
                free(array_pointer);
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                array->array = array_pointer;
                struct string * memc = memcpy(array->array+array->size+1, array_item, sizeof(struct string));
                array->size += 1;
            
                num_bytes = (array->size)*(sizeof(struct string));
                printf("+ Item copied to array - new_item (%s) - Array size in bytes (%d)\n\n", memc->data, num_bytes);
            }
        }
    
        if(array->size == 0)
        {
            struct string * memc = memcpy(array->array+0, array_item, sizeof(struct string));
            array->size += 1;
        
            struct string * new_item = memc;
            num_bytes = (array->size)*(sizeof(struct string));
            printf("+ Item copied to array - new_item (%s) - Array size in bytes (%d)\n\n", new_item->data, num_bytes);
        }
    
    }    
}
```

I call these functions with this script, located in my main function;

```
Array_Init(&Console_Array, STRING_ARRAY);

char buffer[100];
snprintf(buffer, 100, "The Array is storing one string...");
struct string * str = makeString(buffer);

char buffer1[100];
snprintf(buffer1, 100, "The Array is storing two strings...");
struct string * str1 = makeString(buffer1);

char buffer2[100];
snprintf(buffer2, 100, "The Array is storing three strings...");
struct string * str2 = makeString(buffer2);

Array_Add(&Console_Array, str);
Array_Add(&Console_Array, str1);
Array_Add(&Console_Array, str2);
```

The problem I am having is that I believe my array has items within it, I believe this because after debugging the output of my program looks like this;

```
Size of struct string (16)

Initialized Console Array Size in bytes (16) 

###################################################

@:- String Array Type Detected - Copying Item 1 To String Array
+ Item copied to array - new_item (The Array is storing one string..) - Array size in bytes (16)

@:- String Array Type Detected - Copying Item 2 To String Array
+ Number of bytes to reallocate (32)
+ Item copied to array - new_item (The Array is storing two strings..) - Array size in bytes (32)

@:- String Array Type Detected - Copying Item 3 To String Array
+ Number of bytes to reallocate (48)
+ Item copied to array - new_item (The Array is storing three strings..) - Array size in bytes (48)

###################################################
Console Array Size After Adding in bytes (48)
```

I use the following code snippet to try and print out the contents of the array items;

```
for(int i = 0; i < Console_Array.size; i++)
{
    struct string * Array_Element = Console_Array.array+i;
    
    printf("Message (%s)\n\n", (char *)Array_Element->data); // PROBLEM HERE
}
```

I have also tried casting as follows;

```
void * pCA = Console_Array.array;

for(int i = 0; i < Console_Array.size; i++)
{   
    int itype = ((struct string *)pCA+i)->type;
    int ilength = ((struct string *)pCA+i)->length;
    char * cdata = ((struct string *)pCA+i)->data;
    
    printf("@---------------------------------------\n");
    printf("[%i] Array Element \n", i );
    printf("Type   (%i)\n", itype);
    printf("Length (%i)\n", ilength);
    //printf("strnlen (%i)\n", strlen(cdata));
    //printf("Data (%s)\n", cdata);
    printf("Pointer to CA[%i] (%p)\n", i, pCA+i );
}
```

Which gives me the following output;

```
@---------------------------------------
[0] Array Element 
Type   (1082183808)
Length (647863085)
Pointer to CA[0] (0x561f9d9b1670)
@---------------------------------------
[1] Array Element 
Type   (86)
Length (0)
Pointer to CA[1] (0x561f9d9b1671)
@---------------------------------------
[2] Array Element 
Type   (0)
Length (0)
Pointer to CA[2] (0x561f9d9b1672)
```

The type variable should be "3", the length should be the length of the string+1. This is why I think there's a problem with the underlying data.

Firstly, I am looking for someone to point out why the value stored at the array element is not being printed to screen and I receive a segmentation fault.

What I think I have to resolve is a [void pointer to an array of struct strings, that contain pointers to an array of chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L79l.png)

Secondly, I am looking for someone to explain how I access the data held in the struct string located at Console_Array.array+i, preferably with some example code so I can see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Why is `string.type` a pointer, and what doesn't `makeString()` initialize it?

Comment: Why doesn't `Array_Init()` use `makeString()` rather than allocating a `struct string` by itself?

Comment: Note: `strncpy()` doesn't do what you think it does. It is *not* a safer `strcpy()`, but a conversion function for interfacing with fixed-field data like 1960s database records. Use `snprintf()` to safely copy strings.

Comment: If you note clearly where sizes are in bytes and where they're in number of objects, the problem will become very clear. Using ambiguous names like `size` is not doing you any favors. Use things like `num_bytes` or `num_entries`.

Comment: I guess the idea is that *no* string terminator is needed in the custom type. The `struct string` naming is poor, since it is not a C string being stored.

Comment: Because I have just added it and haven't implemented it into the function yet...This is prototype code...that I am trying to put together and learn about dynamic arrays, structures and memory allocation and reallocation...I didn't even notice I had set it as a pointer Barmar so thank you for pointing that out...luser droog, David Schwartz, Weather Vane, all noted and I will proceed with your advice.

Comment: Why does `Array_Init` even need to allocate a `struct string` in the first place? If it's creating an empty array, you don't need to allocate anything.

Comment: You don't need to free the pointer when `malloc()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: It is recommended to store null-terminated C strings. Character arrays without a null-terminator are not very useful as they do not interoperate nicely with the outside world. Therefore you probably should use `malloc(s2->length+1)` and `strcpy`.

Comment: `sizeof(array->array)` doesn't do what you think it does. It is the size of the pointer, not the size of the array it is pointing to. The size of the pointer isn't going to change as it points to differently sized arrays. If it is 8 on your system, it will always be 8. It makes little sense to print it.

Comment: Your structs do not store strings. A string is a null-terminated array of characters. Your arrays lack null termination. You cannot print non-null-terminated character arrays with `%s` format specifier.

Comment: So in my makeString function, if I use snprintf( s2->data, s2->length, "%s\0", s );, will that be sufficient?

Comment: You need to allocate space for that 0, that is, allocate one byte more than strlen(s). It also makes no sense to use snprintf. Why not just use strcpy? There is enough space by construction.

Comment: Would I be right, that from the root of the array structure, if everything was working as it should, I would have a void pointer to an array or struct strings, that hold pointers to char arrays (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L79l.png). To answer your question, "Note: strncpy() doesn't do what you think it does. It is not a safer strcpy(), but a conversion function for interfacing with fixed-field data like 1960s database records. Use snprintf() to safely copy strings"(luser droog).

Comment: Just to clarify, I add s2->length = strlen(s)+1;, then once the space is allocated I would snprintf ( s2->data, s2->length, "%s\0", s );...

Comment: To further answer your question about strncpy(), there's a whole debate on the issue at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606539/snprintf-vs-strcpy-etc-in-c?rq=1#:~:text=snprintf%20is%20more%20robust%20if,strcpy)%20since%20it's%20more%20efficient.&text=sprintf%20has%20an%20extremely%20useful%20return%20value%20that%20allows%20for%20efficient%20appending.

Comment: I didn't say strncpy. I said strcpy.

Comment: Show where `Console_Array` is declared before `Array_Init(&Console_Array, STRING_ARRAY);` In fact, [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help greatly. Without one we are left to make assumptions about how you got to where you are in the code shown. The `printf("Message (%s)\n\n", Array_Element->data);` error is simple `data` is type `void*` and you are attempting to print though a conversion specifier `"%s"` which take type `char*`. So if you are sure your data is correct, cast it, `(char*)Array_Element->data`

Comment: Note: the cast with correct the warning you receive, but will not correct defects in the underlying data pointed to by `data`.

Comment: Console_Array is declared in a common header file; extern Array Console_Array; // In common.h and in Array Console_Array;// In common.c And, that is the problem, I am unsure where the problem is and I am asking for help in finding this out. I think that there is a problem with the underlying data.